# C# Hide mouse cursor on the specific position after specific time

Tags: c#

I want to hide mouse cursor on the specific position ( like a button ) after specific time (like 2 seconds ) of my application in C# by visual studio 2012. How can i do that? Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us a code snippet or some effort done on your side in order to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events using a different thread to wait a couple of seconds before hiding your cursor using `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide()`


This is a code example using WPF but can be easily replicated to WinForms:

```
private void Button_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(HideMouse).Start();
}

private void Button_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    stopHiding.Set();
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Show();
}

private AutoResetEvent stopHiding = new AutoResetEvent(false);

private void HideMouse()
{
    if (!stopHiding.WaitOne(2000))
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using MouseEnter event, get how much time passed. For example you can start a timer with 2 seconds interval when MouseEnter occures and stop the timer when MouseLeave event occurs. If the timer's Tick event triggered, it means that 2 seconds passed as you wished.

Now you should hide the cursor using the control's MouseCursor property to No:

```
label1.MouseCursor = MouseCursor.No;
```

Don't forget to change MouseCursor to default when MouseLeave occurs.

Comment: Thanks for giving Idea.